# Python - cut only the descending part of the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a timeseries with various downcasts. My question is how do I slice a pandas dataframe (or in this case the array, just to keep it simple) to get **the data and its indexes** of the **descending** bits of the timeseries?[image: downcast]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


b = np.asarray([  1.3068586 ,   1.59882279,   2.11291473,   2.64699527,
     3.23948166,   3.81979878,   4.37630243,   4.97740025,
     5.59247254,   6.18671493,   6.77414586,   7.43078595,
     8.02243495,   8.59612224,   9.22302662,   9.83263379,
    10.43125902,  11.0956864 ,  11.61107838,  12.09616684,
    12.63973254,  12.49437955,  11.6433792 ,  10.61083269,
     9.50534291,   8.47418827,   7.40571742,   6.56611512,
     5.66963658,   4.89748187,   4.10543794,   3.44828054,
     2.76866318,   2.24306623,   1.68034463,   1.26568186,
     1.44548443,   2.01225076,   2.60715524,   3.21968562,
     3.8622007 ,   4.57035958,   5.14021305,   5.77879484,
     6.42776897,   7.09397923,   7.71722028,   8.30860725,
     8.96652218,   9.66157193,  10.23469208,  10.79889453,
    10.5788411 ,   9.38270646,   7.82070643,   6.74893389,
     5.68200335,   4.73429009,   3.78358222,   3.05924946,
     2.30428171,   1.78052369,   1.27897065,   1.16840532,
     1.59452726,   2.13085096,   2.70989933,   3.3396291 ,
     3.97318058,   4.62429262,   5.23997774,   5.91232803,
     6.5906609 ,   7.21099657,   7.82936331,   8.49636247,
     9.15634983,   9.76450244,  10.39680729,  11.04659976,
    11.69287237,  12.35692643,  12.99957563,  13.66228386,
    14.31806385,  14.91871927,  15.57212978,  16.22288287,
    16.84697357,  17.50502002,  18.15907842,  18.83068151,
    19.50945548,  20.18020639,  20.84441358,  21.52792846,
    22.17933087,  22.84614545,  23.51212887,  24.18308399,
    24.8552263 ,  25.51709528,  26.18724379,  26.84531493,
    27.50690265,  28.16610365,  28.83394822,  29.49621179,
    30.15118676,  30.8019521 ,  31.46714114,  32.1213546 ,
    32.79366952,  33.45233007,  34.12158193,  34.77502197,
    35.4532211 ,  36.11018053,  36.76540453,  37.41746323])

 plt.plot(-b)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: get the diff and set it less than 0

Comment: Those data produce a plot reflected over the y-axis from the plot you show in your post.

Comment: @andrew_reece, sorry, I forgot to add a minus in front of b, now it's correct I think

Comment: @Wen, would you care to elaborate it a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change the negative diffs to `NaN` and then plot:

```
bb = pd.Series(-b)
bb[bb.diff().ge(0)] = np.nan
bb.plot()
```

[image: plot]

To get the indexes of descending values, use:

```
bb.index[bb.diff().lt(0)]

Int64Index([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,
             14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,  42,
             43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  65,  66,  67,  68,
             69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,
             82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,
             95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107,
            108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119],
           dtype='int64')
```

Comment: you get the indexes with the second line...i'll update to demonstrate.

Comment: in your post you say you want "indexes of the descending bits", but here you say you just want "indexes of this array where it *starts* descending".  which is it?

Comment: it's the whole descending bits , not just the first one. thanks for pointing the issue out

Comment: just our of curiosity: how would you get only the first element of each descent? So for example: 1, 37, 65 in this case?

Answer (score 1):

create a second dataframe where you move everyting from one index then you do it by substracting them term to term. you should get what you want (getting only the ones with negative diff)
here:

```
df = DataFrame(b)
df = concat([df.shift(1),df],axis = 1)
df.columns = ['t-1','t']
df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df['diff'] = df['t']-df['t-1']
res = df[df['diff']<0]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also an easy numpy-only solution (the question is tagged `pandas` but the code uses only `numpy`) using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). You want the points where the graph is descending which means the data is ascending.

```
# the indices where the data is ascending.
ix, = np.where(np.diff(b) > 0)
# the values
c = b[ix]
```

Note that this will give you the first value in each ascending pair of consecutive values, while the pandas-based solution gives the second one. To get the same indices just add `1` to `ix`.

```
s = pd.Series(b)
assert np.all(s[s.diff() > 0].index == ix + 1)
assert np.all(s[s.diff() > 0] == b[ix + 1])
```

Comment: thank you, I just do not understand the second part of the code. What's the purpose of assert?

Comment: @PEBKAC The purpose is to show that using `ix + 1` as the index you get the same indices and values than using pandas.